# Sacar promedios de un array multidimensional javascript

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, angular7

Tengo el siguiente array multidimensional

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imprime los siguientes datos:

```
filtrados = [
[],
[{"edad":40,"sexo":"hombre","partido":"PRI"},{"edad":30,"sexo":"hombre","partido":"PRI"}],
[{"edad":35,"sexo":"mujer","partido":"PAN"},{"edad":25,"sexo":"hombre","partido":"PAN"}],
[{"edad":10,"sexo":"mujer","partido":"PT"}],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
];
```

Tengo que sacar el **promedio de edad y sexo por partido**, ya estan filtrados por partidos porque un array representa un partido pero no logro realizar los promedios. Actualmente este es mi fragmento de codigo:

```
this.politicians.forEach((politicos) => {
      this.politico = politicos;

      this.partidosBD.forEach((partidos) => {
        this.partidos = partidos;

        var filtrados = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < this.partidos.length; i++) {
//FILTRADO POR PARTIDOS
          filtrados.push(this.politico.filter((a) => this.partidos[i].name.includes(a.partidoPolitico)));

        }

        console.log(filtrados);

    //RECORRO EL ARRAY
        for (let i = 0; i < filtrados.length; i++) {
          console.log("Arreglo #" + i);
          for (let j = 0; j < filtrados[i].length; j++) {
    //COMPRUEBO SI EL ARRAY NO ESTA VACIO, ENTIENDO AQUI SE DEBE APLICAR LOS PROMEDIOS
            if (filtrados[i].length > 0) {
              console.log("Edad #" + JSON.stringify(j) + " " + JSON.stringify(filtrados[i][j].age));

            }
          }
        }

      });
    });
```

El sacar promedio entiendo es la suma de los valores en `edad` entre `edad.length` y `sexo` es el total de `hombres` y `mujeres` pero no logro plasmar la funciòn. Los resultados deben ser guardados en un array unidimensional del mismo tamaño del array multidimensional como este ejemplo que es de 9 elementos. Resultado esperado:

prom_edad = [
    0,
    70,
    60,
    10,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
        ]

prom_sexo_h = [
        0,
        2,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
            ]

prom_sexo_m = [
        0,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
            ]

Answer (score 1):

El calculo del promedio seria el siguiente:

promedio = suma de los elementos / la cantidad de esos elementos.

Prueba con el siguiente código:

sustituye tu código //RECORRO EL ARRAY por este código

```
    let prom_edad = [];
    let prom_sexo_h = [];
    let prom_sexo_m= [];
    let suma_edades;
    let cont_sexo_h;
    let cont_sexo_m;

    filtrados.forEach( item => {
      console.log("Arreglo #" + item);
      item.forEach(elemento => {
        // sumas las edades
        suma_edades = suma_edades + elemento['age'];
        // verificas si es hombre o mujer
        if (elemento['sexo'] === 'hombre') {
          // en caso de ser hombre incrementas el contador de hombres
          cont_sexo_h++;
        } else {
          // en caso de ser mujer incrementas el contador de mujeres
          cont_sexo_m++;
        }
      });
      //se agrega el promedio con push(dentro de push se calcula el promedio)
      prom_edad.push(suma_edades / elemento.length);
      prom_sexo_h.push(cont_sexo_h / elemento.length);
      prom_sexo_m.push(cont_sexo_h / elemento.length);
      console.log('El promedio de edad es de: ', prom_edad);
      console.log('El promedio de hombres es de: ', prom_sexo_h);
      console.log('El promedio de mujeres es de: ', prom_sexo_m);
    });
```

Comment: Intenta dar alguna explicación además de subir el código. Así tu respuesta tendrá más valor tanto para el usuario que preguntó como para otros que la lean luego.